# Deploy Service Fabric app on Windows 10

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-service-fabric, service-fabric-stateful

Is it possible to run a release/production version of Service Fabric application on a Windows 10 machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: no, only local development clusters can.

When running on Azure it comes with Windows Server by default. (I think it is 2012 R2)

When running on-premises these are the requirements ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-cluster-standalone-deployment-preparation))

> Step 2: Prepare the machines to meet the prerequisites
>   Prerequisites for each machine that you want to add to the cluster:
>
> - A minimum of 16 GB of RAM is recommended.
> - A minimum of 40 of GB available disk space is recommended.
> - A 4 core or greater CPU is recommended.
> - Connectivity to a secure network or networks for all machines.
> - **Windows Server 2012 R2 or Windows Server 2016.**
> - .NET Framework 4.5.1 or higher, full install.
> - Windows PowerShell 3.0.
> - The RemoteRegistry service should be running on all the machines.